# Python Calculator: What should I add?

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, calculator

```
def start():
    import time
    ans = input("Do you wish to start again? [y/n]\n")
    if ans == 'y' or ans == "yes" or ans == "":
        print(' \n' * 30)
        main()
    elif ans == 'n' or ans == "no":
        exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid Input\n")
        time.sleep(3)
        start()


def main():
    import math
    import time
    print("Calculator:\n")
    aa = float(input("First number- "))
    ans = float(
        input(" do you want to:\n Add (1)\n Subtract (2)\n Multiply (3)\n Devide (4)\n Calculate an Exponent (5)\n "
              "Calculate Circumference(6)\n Calculate the Area of a Circle(7)\n Square Root(8)\n"))
    if ans == 6:
        print("If given diameter, Circumference is " + (aa * math.pi))
        start()
    if ans == 7:
        print("If given radius, Area is ")
        print(aa ** 2 * math.pi)
    if ans == 8:
        print("the square root of", + aa, "is", + (aa ** (1.0 / 2)))
        time.sleep(3)
        start()

    bb = float(input("Second Number- "))

    if ans == 1:
        print(aa + bb)
    elif ans == 2:
        print(aa - bb)
    elif ans == 3:
        print(aa * bb)
    elif ans == 4:
        print(aa / bb)
    elif ans == 5:
        print(aa ** bb)
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
    time.sleep(2.5)
    print(' \n' * 30)
    start()


main()
```

I was curious if my calculator is good or needs more functions, how I would do that, etc. I really want to make it able to keep the output and assign it to a variable that I can call to add, subtract, multiply, etc. I'm new to python, or coding for that matter, but I just want to make a great calculator that has easy to use and useful functions. So I just want to know, what should I add or change?

Comment: This community is called Code Review - you seem to be asking for a *product specification* review.

Comment: What kind of calculator is it? The use of `math.pi` isn't something I would expect in a normal calculator.

Comment: Hello Jaxon, as greybeard stated, we can review your actual code with the functions it has right now, but we can't really help you figure out which functions to add, this is up to you to figure it out :)

If you'd like for the code you have right now to be reviewed, you should edit your post to make it clear, otherwise your post will get closed for being off-topic.

Comment: It's easy to add new features to a well-written program.  I'd suggest the next function to be added to this is #9:  take a number and add it to the previous result.

Answer (score 2):

"*What you should add*" is an off-topic question for **Code Review**.  Here, we only review complete, working code.  You will get feedback on areas of your program that need work, where code could be designed better, perform better, handle input or errors more gracefully.  "*What you should add*" is an open-ended question that you (or your program's users) should answer.

---

### Imports

Imports should be listed at the top of the file, preceded only by a `"""docstring"""` if one is present.

Importing inside of functions

```
def start():
    import time
    ...
```

leads to needed to import the same modules over and over again, and provides little benefit.  It is only useful in cases of optional functionality, where an module may not be installed and failing to importing it would not prevent the rest of the program from running.  This is not the case here.  Move all your imports out of method to the top of the file:

```
import time
import math

def start():
    ...
```

### Infinite Recursion

If you eventually add the capability of storing values in variables, so you could do more complex calculations, involving long chains of operations, would you want your calculator to ***CRASH*** after 500 computations?

Python's stack is not unlimited.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getrecursionlimit()
1000
```

With a limit of 1000 calls, your implementation of `main()` calling `start()`, which calls `main()`, which calls `start()`, which calls `main()`, which calls `start()`, which calls ... will crash after 500 calls of `main()` and 500 calls of `start()`.  And any values stored in variables would probably be lost.

Don't use infinite recursion where a simple `while ...:` loop would do.

### Exit

Don't use `exit()`.  This unconditionally terminates the Python interpreter.  Unit tests written in Python will not be able to examine results and report success or failure if the code it is testing calls `exit()`.  A caller which expects to continue executing after using the calculator cannot recover from `exit()`.  Never, ever use it.

### Garbage Output

```
print(' \n' * 30)
```

Why is there a space before the newline?  Did you mean to print out "space" "newline" "space" "newline" "space" "newline" ... "space" "newline" "space" "newline"?  How is that different from just printing out 30 newlines?

### Error Recovery

If the user enters an invalid value at the `"First number- "` prompt, such as `1.000.000`, the program will crash with a `ValueError`.  You should use `try: ... catch ...: ...` blocks to catch illegal input problems, and recover.

Similarly, you should be prepared for errors in calculation, such as division by zero, or square-roots of negative numbers.

### Printing

```
    print("If given diameter, Circumference is " + (aa * math.pi))

    print("If given radius, Area is ")
    print(aa ** 2 * math.pi)

    print("the square root of", + aa, "is", + (aa ** (1.0 / 2)))
```

In the first case, you are joining a string and the results of a calculation.  In the second, you are using 2 print statements.  In the third, you're using separate arguments to the print statement to print multiple values.  Pick one style, and be consistent.

Additionally, the leading `+` signs are not needed in the expression arguments `+ aa` or `+ (aa ** (1.0 / 2))`.  You are not concatenating the value with the previous string; it is a separate argument.  Parenthesis are not required around the `(aa ** (1.0 / 2))` calculation.  It is not necessary to write `(1.0 / 2)`; using `(1 / 2)` would work just fine, as would simply `0.5`.

```
    print("If given diameter, Circumference is", aa * math.pi)

    print("If given radius, Area is", aa ** 2 * math.pi)

    print("the square root of", aa, "is", aa ** 0.5)
```

### Bug

If you ask for "area", after printing the result, the program will then ask for the second number, and will then `print("Invalid input")`.

### Flotsam & Jetsam

- After most calculations, you have a delay of 2.5 seconds.  After square root, you have a delay of 3 seconds.  After circumference, no delay at all.  Intended differences?  Accidental?  Maybe you should have the delay in exactly one spot, so it is consistent.
- `Devide` should be spelt `Divide`
- When you ask for a function value, 1 through 8, you accept floating point values, instead of integers.  It works, but is odd.